# Google Play Android App Internal Testing - Update button not shown to internal testers

Tags: android, google-play, google-developers-console

I have found the other versions of my question on SO and have already tried to contact Google through their dev support trying both the chat/email options, but have yet to get a straight answer about this.

I have an app that is currently using the internal testing track on Google Play. I have numerous testers all of which can download the app, use it and test it no problem. The reason I want to use internal testing, for now, is that the documentation states there is no verification period between versions and testers get the new version immediately.

The issue I am currently experiencing is that a tester who already has the app is not served an updated version when they return to the store page. If they uninstall and reinstall the app, the new app they install serves the new version.

My question is why would the new version be available but not present the user with the 'Update' button to install the new version?

Is there an issue with the app being on the internal test track? Does my app need to be verified? Can an app be verified using the internal test track? It has been 17 days since my initial upload to verify the app, which seems rather long to wait for the verification.

Does anyone have some insight into this issue? I am running out of ideas and it is rather annoying to have testers need to uninstall and reinstall the app every new version I would like tested.

Comment: If the tester is signed in to multiple Google Accounts, make sure they are using the correct one. Also try clearing the Google Play cache data.

Comment: @user14678216 I've tried both. I also have my own google test account. I've waiting multiple days, cleared cache/force quit the app. As the users can see, install and use the app, they are on the correct accounts.

Comment: @user14678216, Thanks! Clearing Google Play cache worked like a charm for me.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

After almost a month I finally have the update button. Here are the steps I took:

1. Create a new Closed Testing Track and go through all steps required to post a closed testing app.
2. Wait until the app is verified and the store page updates with the relevant store page data. (This took ~3-4 business days)
3. I can now publish to the Internal Testing Track, see the Update button, and use it. I no longer need to publish to the Closed Track unless I want to.

I've looked over most of the documentation and nowhere does it say in writing that your build needs to be verified to have the Update button appear, nor does it say anywhere that it is required to be in at least Closed Testing to be verified.

I hope this helps someone else in the near future as this was quite annoying.

Comment: You're so right! I was almost about to give up but your solution saved me. After waiting to get reviewed for 5 days, it's finally showing the update button. Thanks!

Comment: This is insane. So you have to get an alpha track release approved before you can use internal testing? My god. Apples TestFlight works so much better than this

Comment: @AndersEmil You are still able to use the internal track and have testers install the app without creating an alpha track. However, testers will need to freshly install the app every time you want them to get a new version. All other functionality works as intended on the internal track without an alpha track.

Comment: Where do you find the internal test app in Google Play.
I can not find it anywhere and it doesn't automatically update or anything.

I can go to it by the link, but that is just cumbersome..

Comment: @SEG.Veenstra After the app is fully reviewed by Google you will be able to just search for it if you are an internal tester.

Comment: @TEEBQNE thank you for the reply. However, I'm still not seeing it.
It has been fully reviewed.

Comment: @SEG.Veenstra Odd. I was able to search for my app even during internal testing. There are a lot of steps to setting up the app so it is hard to say which could be causing the issue. I'd reach out to Google Developer Support as they could probably help a lot more than I can.

Comment: Here in 2023 and this process is still SO confusing. I've tried many variations of internal and closed testing but my test users can never see the new build. Losing my mind.

Answer (score 4):

Although a little cumbersome, when using internal testing, you'll provide your users with a URL where they can download the app (via the play store), note, this URL can be found under your "How testers join your test" section, on your "testers" tab, on your 'Internal testing' page.

When you create a new version, the testers who already have the app installed, can use the same URL provided in the first place, and they can click to download via the play store (counter-intuitive as they already have it), but when it takes them to the play store, it will give them an option to update the app, and you'll see your updated release note ect...

This means you won't need to go through the Closed testing approach and wait to get it verified.

I hope this helps somebody, I didn't want to create a closed tracked and get it verified as my app is very early into dev.